# How to change datetime format of varchar datatype column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How to change datetime format of varchar datatype column in SQL Server.
[image]

Datatype of column [Value] is varchar. I cannot change datatype into datetime because this column contains numeric values also. This table is being updated by query. I need the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h). How?

Comment: What SQL Server version?

Comment: `268142` means what? Julian date?

Comment: Seems like a poor choice for a relational database design...

Comment: Please advise what should be!

Comment: Dates should be kept as dates, numbers should be kept as numbers. I can't really give any better advice since I don't know anything about your system other then what you've posted here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Try_Convert()` in concert with `IsNull()`

To be clear.  The result is still a string

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Value varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('268142')
,('Jan 1 1900 12:04PM')

Select *
     ,NewVal = IsNull(format(try_convert(datetime,Value),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),Value)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Value                NewVal
268142              268142
Jan 1 1900 12:04PM  1900-01-01 12:04:00
```

> **EDIT**

Format() is not known to be a performer, and should be used sparingly.  Another approach may be

```
NewVal = IsNull(try_convert(varchar(50),try_convert(datetime,Value),120),Value)
```

Comment: I am having an error 'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You tagged 2014.  Select @@Version for your version and Select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases for compatability level.  Should be >=110

Comment: If I change compatibility level to 110, would be there impact on my DB?

Comment: @MuhammadAliKhamis For the better, but you really need to check with your DBA.  There may be a reason for 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can use this case-convert statement:

```
declare @date varchar(max)
set @date='Jan 1 1999 12:00AM'

Select case when right(@date,2)='AM' then convert(datetime,SUBSTRING(@date,1,len(@date)-2)+':00',121)
                else dateadd(hour,12,convert(datetime,SUBSTRING(@date,1,len(@date)-2)+':00',121)) end
```